# How to preload a dialog

Tags: android, android-layout, dialog, android-alertdialog

I have a custom dialog and despite putting in all the code to inflate the view in its constructor, it seems like it takes much longer when the dialog is first launched compared to subsequent launches, as if only when i call dialog.show(); it actually creates it. How could I do what I intended, to properly preload the dialog to prevent this first run delay?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can Extend your class with AsyncTask<> and perform all work in doInBackground().in onPreExecute() Show Dialog and in onPostExecute() remove the dialog from UI.